# I don't have access to class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created Class named *RSSCollection*

```
namespace RSSHandler
{
    public class RSSCollection
    {
        public static void checkRSS()
        {
         ...
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use it in *Global.ascx* file like this

```
namespace RSSHandler
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RSSCollection.checkRSS();
        }
    }
}
```

but Visual Studio tells me "*the name "RSSCollection" doesn't exist in the current context*"

where's the problem ? both classes are public

**Update**: this's the structure of the code

[image]

Comment: Given they are in the same namespace and the method is static, that should just work. Does the project compile successfully?

Comment: What you provided looks valid. Could you add a screenshot of the solution explorer?

Comment: *I don't have access to class* Is that the question?

Comment: Is the class defined in another DLL by any chance?

Comment: it could be that vs has bugged out, try cleaning the solution, restarting vs and deleting the cache. the code looks fine

Comment: You code is 100% OK, the problem probably comes from the structure of the solution

Comment: @CodeCaster it returns compile error

Comment: If you fully qualify? RSSHandler.RSSCollection.checkRSS(); ?

Comment: There is something wrong in what you didn't show us at all.

Comment: Then you need to fix that. Show the actual compiler error.

Comment: please see the structure of the code, i have updated the question

Comment: Set the Build Action of the RSSCollection.cs file to Content instead of Compile if it is in App_code folder

Comment: @RahulNikate can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Try removing the RSSCollection.checkRSS()  from the Global.ascx and build the complete project. If its succeeded add the same on the Global.ascx and rebuild it .... this is just another try

Comment: @RahulNikate it's already "Content" (not "Compile")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Build Action of the RSSCollection.cs file to Compile instead of Content if it is in App_code folder. After this build your project by temporarily commenting line `RSSHandler.RSSCollection.checkRSS();` then access it like `RSSHandler.RSSCollection.checkRSS();`

```
namespace RSSHandler
{
    public class RSSCollection
    {
        public static void checkRSS()
        {
         ...
        }
    }
}



namespace RSSHandler
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          RSSHandler.RSSCollection.checkRSS();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right click on file properties -> Build Action

Comment: @CodeCaster Based on what are you saying this. Have tested your end. It's not fair to down vote

Comment: after "RSSHandler", visual studio doesn't see any "App_Code". VS see only Global file !

Comment: @dotfreelancer you need to build your project after setting build action to compile then you will be able to access. Temporarily comment line in global.asax

Comment: @RahulNikate now too many classes and namespaces are not accessible, like "System.ServiceModel"

Comment: @RahulNikate it works now, i just added necessary references.. thanks

Comment: @RahulNikate I upvote it, I don't know what's the problem with developers here.. my question also have 2 downvotes.. for what? i don't know.. anyway.. thank you

Comment: @CodeCaster I hope I'm correct here. It works as per my answer. You can check your side. Thanks